# Diagnosing Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).createServer is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments

I have a vue project utilizing Stripe, however, just recently when I loaded up my workspace this error has been happening and I am pretty lost on how I can diagnose it.

Interestingly enough, my live version is working with no errors and they are the same exact version.

I searched around for the last couple hours to see if I could find a fix and I updated all of my projects plugins with no luck. I am not sure what step to take now.

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).createServer is not a function
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js:9)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js:354)
    at Object../node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js (app.js:7341)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1427)
    at fn (app.js:801)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:24)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:8065)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:1427)
    at fn (app.js:801)
    at Object.1 (app.js:8572)
```

here is the error

Comment: This might help, for a cleaner client-side implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849142/8500237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates you're likely using [`stripe`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe) (intended to run server-side in Node) in the browser. You should switch to [`stripe-client`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe-client) or import the `stripe.js` [from CDN](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs).